Join without range
I'm working on  problem where I've two datasets like below.
Dataset A, where max periods can be from upto 10 year periods and there are 1 million unique magicNames, for example as of now its 202401 to 202403 period:
magicName  period
magicOne   202401
magicTwo   202402
magicThree 202403
..... so on

Another dataset B:
magicName  periodRange
magicOne   19001-299901
magicTwo   202501-299901
magicThree 202403-299901

As of now, I'm normalizing dataset B periodRange to Period, where max period range is for entry is min and max period range of dataset A. So dataset B will look like this. (magicTwo range doesn't fit in min and max of Dataset A, and magicThree range only fits for 202403).
magicName  period
magicOne   202401
magicOne   202402
magicOne   202403
magicThree 202403

Now I join A and B.
My problem is I don't want to normalize dataset B to join with A, because if I normalize it for all 1 million magic for 10 years period, records become in millions.
Secondly don't want to use range calculation for join, don't know, but not liking it doing that way.
Third, Is there any way I could create any mapping for periodRange, so that if I just simply join with A, it gives me output?
I'm working on Apache Spark project, but I think its more of a SQL/algo problem.

May be you should split periodRange into two fields like PeriodFrom and PeriodTo?

Please update your question with the result you are trying to achieve, based on the sample data in Tables A & B

It is not clear what are you expecting as a result cause there is no explanation what are you doing after

Now I join A and B.

We know just that

(magicTwo range doesn't fit in min and max of Dataset A, and magicThree range only fits for 202403)

The first thing to do could be to prepare your data for the final selection in a way that you collect all your data of interest in the same row. The most important thing to do is to work with DATE datatype instead of string/text/varchar. That could be done creating a cte to prepare the data and filter magicTwo out (if needed, I'm not sure about that).
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl_a AS
( Select 'magicOne' as magicName, '202401' as period Union All
  Select 'magicTwo', '202402' Union All 
  Select 'magicThree', '202403' );

Create Table tbl_b AS
( Select 'magicOne' as magicName, '190001-299901' as periodRange Union All
  Select 'magicTwo', '202501-299901' Union All 
  Select 'magicThree', '202403-299901'  );

Below is the code that will fetch you all the dates needed for selection/comparison/filtering in every row - it could be either declared as a cte or used as a subquery to outer query that gives you the result you want whatever the result could be:
--    S Q L : 
Select  a.magicName, a.period, 
        To_Date(a.period, 'yyyymm') As periodMonth, mm.minPeriod, mm.maxPeriod,
        b.periodRange, b.startRange, b.endRange
From    tbl_a a
Inner Join ( Select    Min(To_Date(period, 'yyyymm')) as minPeriod, 
                       Max(To_Date(period, 'yyyymm')) as maxPeriod
             From      tbl_a 
           ) mm ON( 1 = 1 )
Inner Join ( Select magicName, periodRange, 
                    To_Date(SubStr(periodRange, 1, InStr(periodRange, '-') - 1), 'yyyymm') as startRange, 
                    To_Date(SubStr(periodRange, InStr(periodRange, '-') + 1, 6), 'yyyymm') as endRange
             From tbl_b
           ) b ON(b.magicName = a.magicName )
Where      To_Date(a.period, 'yyyymm') Between b.startRange And b.endRange

/*      R e s u l t :
MAGICNAME   PERIOD  PERIODMONTH MINPERIOD   MAXPERIOD   PERIODRANGE     STARTRANGE  ENDRANGE
----------  ------  ----------- ----------  ----------  --------------  ----------  ---------
magicOne    202401  01-JAN-24   01-JAN-24   01-MAR-24   190001-299901   01-JAN-00   01-JAN-99
magicThree  202403  01-MAR-24   01-JAN-24   01-MAR-24   202403-299901   01-MAR-24   01-JAN-99    */

See thee fiddle here.
NOTE
The code above is tested with Oracle (don't know your rdbms) and it should be adjusted to your environment. There shouldn't be any problems with that cause it is a very basic SQL syntax.
